# Array iteration and merging using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have an array like : `

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [productid] => 141
                    [fieldid] => 2
                    [value] => Laptop
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [productid] => 191
                    [fieldid] => 2
                    [value] => Books
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [productid] => 177
                    [fieldid] => 2
                    [value] => Printer
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [productid] => 141
                    [fieldid] => 1
                    [value] => 3
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [productid] => 191
                    [fieldid] => 1
                    [value] => 4
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [productid] => 177
                    [fieldid] => 1
                    [value] => 2
                )

        )

)`
```

I want this array to be modified and looks like the following :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [productid] => 141
            [fieldid] => 2
            [value] => Laptop
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [productid] => 191
            [fieldid] => 2
            [value] => Books
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [productid] => 177
            [fieldid] => 2
            [value] => Printer
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [productid] => 141
            [fieldid] => 1
            [value] => 3
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [productid] => 191
            [fieldid] => 1
            [value] => 4
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [productid] => 177
            [fieldid] => 1
            [value] => 2
        )
)
```

Just remove the outer array and combine all chunks of array into one. Is this possible in php. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach could be this:

Lets say `$items` is your original array,

```
$new_items = array();
foreach($items as $item)
{
    $new_items = array_merge($new_items,array_values($item));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use the following method to do that.Quite simple.

```
//let the older array be $array
var $newArray = array();  //new array(all itms will be taken to this array)      
foreach($array as $key->$value){
    foreach($value as $key->$innervalue){
            $newArray[] = $innervalue;
             }

    }
```